# Variable number formatter in text field

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to insert a number into a Text Field.

If the is larger then 0.001 the number should be displayed as 1.234 (0.000).
If the is smaller then 0.001 the number should be displayed as 1.234E-5 (0.000E+0).

I had a look in "LOCALE DATA MARKUP LANGUAGE (LDML)" using Choice Patterns but this seems not to work from Interface Builder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on "changes ended" or whatever it is on the Mac.

```
- (IBAction) checkFloat: (id)sender
{
    double test = [sender doubleValue];
    if (test > 0.001)
        [sender setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%E",test];

    // etc.

}
```

[Look up string formats here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)